# Laravel 5 pagination using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

when i use laravel pagination my page is displayed twice...
my controller is like this......

controller.php

```
 public function index()
    {

        $restaurant = Restaurant::leftjoin('cities','restaurant.city','=','cities.id')
             ->leftjoin('cuisine','restaurant.cuisine','=','cuisine.id')
             ->select('*','restaurant.id as id','restaurant.created_at as user_created')
             ->paginate(3);

        $restaurant ->setPath('/elitecard/stores');
               return view('front_end.stores.stores',compact('restaurant'));
    }
```

blade.php

```
<div class="pagination-stores">
   {!! $restaurant->render() !!}
</div>
<div id="ajaxContent">
</div>

<script>
$('#ajaxContent').load('http://localhost/elitecard/stores');

$('.pagination a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $(this).attr('href') != '#' ) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
        $('#ajaxContent').load($(this).attr('href'));
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load 'href' of your rendered links it return you full view. You have `return view('front_end.stores.stores',compact('restaurant'));` 
try this:

```
$('body').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

insead of this:

```
$('#ajaxContent').load($(this).attr('href'));
```